# How to use Page Objects in Selenium

Tags: object, selenium

I have the below code. I want to reuse the functions in another java file. How can do that using Page Objects?

```
public class LoginPage {


      private final WebDriver driver;

        public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;

            // Check that we're on the right page.
            if (!"Outreach Configuration".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
                // Alternatively, we could navigate to the login page, perhaps logging out first
                throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the login page");
            }
        }

        // The login page contains several HTML elements that will be represented as WebElements.
        // The locators for these elements should only be defined once.

        //    By usernameLocator = By.name("username");
        //    By passwordLocator = By.name("password");
            By loginButtonLocator = By.name("submit");

        // The login page allows the user to type their username into the username field
        public LoginPage typeUsername(String username) {
            // This is the only place that "knows" how to enter a username
            driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(username);

            // Return the current page object as this action doesn't navigate to a page represented by another PageObject
            return this;    
        }

        // The login page allows the user to type their password into the password field
        public LoginPage typePassword(String password) {
            // This is the only place that "knows" how to enter a password
            //driver.findElement(passwordLocator).sendKeys(password);
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
            // Return the current page object as this action doesn't navigate to a page represented by another PageObject
            return this;    
        }

        // The login page allows the user to submit the login form
        public HomePage submitLogin() {
            // This is the only place that submits the login form and expects the destination to be the home page.
            // A seperate method should be created for the instance of clicking login whilst expecting a login failure. 
           driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).submit();

            // Return a new page object representing the destination. Should the login page ever
            // go somewhere else (for example, a legal disclaimer) then changing the method signature
            // for this method will mean that all tests that rely on this behaviour won't compile.
            return new HomePage(driver);    
        }

        // The login page allows the user to submit the login form knowing that an invalid username and / or password were entered
        public LoginPage submitLoginExpectingFailure() {
            // This is the only place that submits the login form and expects the destination to be the login page due to login failure.
        //    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).submit();

            // Return a new page object representing the destination. Should the user ever be navigated to the home page after submiting a login with credentials 
            // expected to fail login, the script will fail when it attempts to instantiate the LoginPage PageObject.
            return new LoginPage(driver);   
        }

        // Conceptually, the login page offers the user the service of being able to "log into"
        // the application using a user name and password. 
        public HomePage loginAs(String username, String password) {
            // The PageObject methods that enter username, password & submit login have already defined and should not be repeated here.
            typeUsername(username);
            typePassword(password);
            return submitLogin();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            // And now use this to visit Google
            driver.get("");
            LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HomePage a=login.loginAs("username","password");
            System.out.println(a);
            //driver.findElement(By.className("newbutton")).click();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `main()` method should not be part of the Page Object, just move it to it's own class. 
The `LoginPage` already follows the Page Object pattern, and can be reused wherever required, for example in another main method or another class.

In the most simple case, Page Object classes and the class containing the execution logic should be part of the same java package and namespace to be able to 'see' each other. Alternatively, you can also have the page objects in another package and use [import](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html).

```
package testing; 

public class LoginPage {
  //all your your code minus the main method 
}

public class LoginTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //your main method logic here

    }
}

public class AnotherLoginTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //you can reuse the LoginPage here and try login with another set of credentials.

    }
}
```

Note: I have not checked whether your login steps are actually correct (not in scope of the question) - you would need to properly navigate to the correct url and then perform your steps.

Comment: how can I call the methods from LoginPage in another java file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a Page object in your methods that you named "typeUsername" and "typePassword".   You only need to return a page object on events which change the DOM/page .

Comment: Yes, doesn't need to. However, it's helpful when chaining actions, such as `login.typeUsername(name).typePassword(pwd).submitLogin()`

Comment: If fluent-api is what you want, I would have done it differently.  You could create an inner class with methods that "return this;" and then instantiate it like this:  login.goFluent().typePassword(x).submitLogin().verify()  ,  etc.  I do that so my Page Objects can work with either fluent behavior or regular.